# How to create a dynamic Table?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to create a dynamic html table element using Jquery .

In This table I want to add the Td inner element as anchor tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

Use the [append](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/append) function

```
$("#divID").append("<table><tr><td><a href='3#'>Click me</a></td></tr></table>");
```

or just create the table markup as string and use the

[html()](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html)

to append it inside a container

```
var strTable = "<table><tr><td><a href='#'>Click</a></td></tr></table>";

$("#div1").html(strTable.toString() );
```

If you have more complex markup then use an array

```
var arrTableMarkup = new Array();
arrTableMarkup.push ( "<table>" );
arrTableMarkup.push (     "<tr>" );
arrTableMarkup.push (       "<td>" );
arrTableMarkup.push (           "<a id='anch1' href='#'>Click</a>" );
arrTableMarkup.push (       "</td>" );
arrTableMarkup.push (       "</tr>" );
arrTableMarkup.push ( "</table>" );

$("#div1").html(arrTableMarkup.join('') );
```

***Edit***

If you need to add an onclick event then you can specify the anchor tag an id and then use the [live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) method to assign event.

```
$("#anch1").live ( "click" , function () { EventHandlerFunction() } );
```

Comment: but I want to add the onclik event to the Anchor Tag Via Jquery Syntax

Comment: +1 but I personally wouldn't use an array, I'd just go with straight text.

Answer (score 1):

Call `createDynamicTable(tbody, rows, cols)`

```
<script typr="text/javascript">
function createDynamicTable(tbody, rows, cols)
{
    if (tbody == null || tbody.length < 1)return;

    for (var r = 1; r <= rows; r++) {
            var trow = $("<tr>");
        for (var c = 1; c <= cols; c++) {
            var input = $("<a />");
            $("<td>")
                    .addClass("tableCell")
                    .append(input)
                    .data("col", c)
                    .appendTo(trow);
        }
        trow.appendTo(tbody);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most simple (and maybe the fastest) way is to do it from HTML:

```
var table = $('<table><tr><td><a href="#">Hello World!</a></td></tr></table>');
```

Doing `table.find('a')` will give you the anchor, if needed.